# Is there a way to remove the padding between the devexpress dropdown control and its div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I have the following image to demonstrate a Devexpress dropdown control in a `<div>` the control has bootstrap set as in the following code snippet

```
    <div style="padding:0px;">
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBoxFor(m => m.FruitList, settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "FruitList";
            settings.Properties.ClientInstanceName = "FruitList";
            settings.Properties.TextField = "FruitName";
            settings.Properties.ValueField = "Id";
            settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);
            settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "form-control";
        }
).BindList(_model.GetFruitList()).GetHtml()
    <div>
```

[image: devexpress control with bootstrap]

As you can see in the image there is a slight gap between the control and the div I have tried setting the `padding:0px;` but it did not work. How do I get rid of the padding between the Devexpress control and `div`?

Comment: can't you just remove the div?

Comment: @AlanTsai i have updated my OP the div should not have bootstrap only the devexpress control has